# Wrong Image is being displayed

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

When I upload an image, there is no error it works fine. But when the image is displayed it shows the wrong image. It's currently showing an image that doesn't even exist. To be true when I was testing the upload function I used the same image all the time so I really didn't find any problem. Now when I upload another image (minion's image), it still displays the old image that I used for testing purpose. I dont know why. I even checked the folder manually and inside the folder, it shows the correct image but this is not the image that is shown in the **view page**.

Below is the code to store the image:

```
   public function store(Request $request)
{
    if(Auth::check())
    {            
        if (Stock::where('tag_no','=',$request->input('tag_no'))->exists()) { 
            return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Tag number already used!');                
        } 

        $this->validate($request, [
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);

        $imageName = 'Tag '.$request->input('tag_no').'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('/storage/'.Auth::user()->company.'/stock-images'), $imageName);   

        $stock = Stock::insert([
            'tag_no' => $request->input('tag_no'),
            'stock_type' => $request->input('stock_type'),                                  
            'image' => $imageName,
        ]);            

        if($stock){                   
            return redirect()->route('stocks.index')
            ->with('success' , 'Stock created successfully');
        }                
    }        
    return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Error creating new Stock');        
}
```

So the path I'm storing is in " **/public/storage/companyname/stock-images/** ".

And in the view page:

```
 <a href="/storage/{{Auth::user()->company}}/stock-images/{{$stock->image}}" target="__blank">
 <img class="pull-right" src="/storage/{{Auth::user()->company}}/stock-images/{{$stock->image}}"  height="100" width="100"></a>
```

I tried clearing cache and config and also view still its the same.
Someone, please suggest me something.

Comment: @Devendar.have you ran php artisan clear or  php artisan cache:clear and php artisan view:clear

Comment: I tried the last two. Lemme try the first one !

Comment: if you running php artisan serve then close terminal once and open terminal again and clear your browser cache and close browser and restart

Comment: No i'm using xampp to host. I tried clearing php artisan clear . Still doesnt work!

Comment: @where you storing iamges in public folder or in storage

Comment: @iCoders it worked... i cleared browser cache.. ! thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run following Commands

```
php artisan clear or php artisan cache:clear
```

and

```
php artisan view:clear
```

if you running `php artisan serve` then close terminal once and open terminal again

Still you are viewing  old image then 
clear your browser cache and  restart browser

Comment: @DevenderGupta If this answer solved your problem mark it as solved by clicking the check mark under the voting arrows

Comment: Was waiting for the option to be available :D

Comment: @DevenderGupta My bad.